# How to search by value and get key in multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
$a['bla1']['blub1']="test123";
$a['bla1']['blub2']="test1234";
$a['bla1']['blub3']="test12345";
$a['bla2']['blub1']="test123456";
$a['bla2']['blub2']="test12344e45";
$a['bla2']['blub3']="test12345335";
```

How to search by value and get back `bla1` or `bla2`? I don't need the subkey, only the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
function searcharray($a, $value)
{
   foreach($a as $key1 => $keyid)
   {

  foreach($keyid as $key => $keyid2)
   {
      if ( $keyid2 === $value )
         return $key.','.$key1;
   }
}
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But i found another solution for my problem. It was way easier than i described above. i could filter the associative array by the first entry in the array and get the last one. Because the "blas" were base urls and the values some specific links.

Answer (score 0):

This function recursively searches an array to any depth and returns the main key under which `$needle` is found:

```
function get_main_key($arr, $needle) {
    $out = FALSE;
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $needle) {
            $out = $key;
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            $ret = get_main_key($value, $needle);
            $out = ( ! empty($ret)) ? $key : $out;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```