# Finding parent in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array, the only value I have is the ID of the child page (35 in this case). I am looking to receive the parent, so I can loop through all children when there are more (I'm looking for the number 34 in this case).

```
[34] => Array
    (
        [id] => 34
        [label] => Over Ons
        [type] => page
        [url] => 8
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 35
                        [label] => Algemeen
                        [type] => page
                        [url] => 9
                    )

            )

    )
```

Does anyone have a good solution for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried _anything_? looks like you're looking for a pretty basic (recursive) loop (function)

Comment: If you generate the array, simple add a **reference** to the parent: `$parent = array(); $child= array(); $child["parent"] = &$parent; $parent[] = $child` - then you can go "upwards" from each child. And dont need to determine the parent by searching the whole array. for the top most, set parent to `null` ofc.

Comment: check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806116/how-to-search-by-value-and-get-key-in-multidimensional-arrays/17806172#17806172

Comment: @dognose nice way to avoid useless computing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value["children"] as $child) {
        if ($child["id"] == $you_look_for) return $key; // or $value["id"] ?
    }
}
```

This - however - will only return the first id of an array containing a child with id `$you_look_for`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$input    = array( /* your data */ );
$parentId = 0;
$childId  = 35;

foreach ( $input as $id => $parent ) {
  foreach ( $parent['children'] as $child ) {
    if ( $child['id'] == $childId ) {
      $parentId = $id;
      break;
    }
  }
  if ( $parentId ) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Or with a function:

```
function searchParent($input, $childId) {
  foreach ( $input as $id => $parent ) {
    foreach ( $parent['children'] as $child ) {
      if ( $child['id'] == $childId ) {
        return $id;
      }
    }
  }
}

$parentId = searchParent($input, $childId);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you build the Array (assuming you are creating it on your own), add a reference to the parent:

```
<?php

$parent = array("id" => 1, "parent" => null);
$child = array("id" => 2, "parent" => &$parent); //store reference
$child2 = array("id" => 3, "parent" => &$parent); //store reference
$parent["childs"][] = $child;
$parent["childs"][] = $child2;

foreach ($parent["childs"] AS $child){
    echo $child["id"]." has parent ".$child["parent"]["id"]. "<br />";
}

//2 has parent 1
//3 has parent 1
?>
```

This allows you to walk the array "very smooth", using `childs` and `parent` entries.
(Basically its a tree, then)

Comment: I am not building this array. It is built by an Magento extension I am trying to modify.